# Javascript + objects + arrays

Tags: javascript

Trying to make this function check the users choice to see if its correct.

```
var state = {
  question: [{
  "questions": "who is David",
  "choices": ["me", "you", "himher"],
  "correct": "me"
  }],
  currentQuestion: 0,
};

function checkAnswer(state, choice){
  if(state.question[0] === state.correct){
    return "correct!!";
  }else {
    return "false";
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How is this function being called? You've got a state object and then a state parameter in your function, as your code stands we don't know anything about that function's state parameter

Comment: How can i access the choices part of the question array

Comment: `state.correct` should be `state.question[0].correct`. I don't even know what you're trying to do with `state.question[0]` because it makes no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to create a quiz app, so the checkAnswer function is suppose to check the users choice.

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly you're stuck on. You clearly know how to access members of arrays and objects, so what's stopping you from accessing `choices`?

Answer (score 0):

If you access your `state` object incrementally using variables, it will be easier to follow. You likely want to use `currentQuestion` to indicate what index to use in the array of questions. I would also suggest changing `correct` so that it likewise indicates the index of the correct choice (in order to prevent potential issues with inconsistent data).

```js
var state = {
  questions: [{
    question: "Who is David?",
    choices: ["me", "you", "himher"],
    correct: 0
  }],
  currentQuestion: 0,
};

function checkAnswer(state, choice) {
  var questionState = state.questions[state.currentQuestion];
  var correctChoice = questionState.choices[questionState.correct];
  return correctChoice === choice;
}

console.log(checkAnswer(state, "me"));
console.log(checkAnswer(state, "you"));
```